# SQL query on certain database names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have many databases on a server. I want to run a query on only databases that end in "AccountsLive".

Not all of them end with this, so I kind of want to do a wildcard %AccountsLive query and not using a `WHERE NOT name IN('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')`

Is this possible?

Below is the code I currently have:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.SL_TRANSACTIONS'
FROM    sys.databases
WHERE   not [name] in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');


EXECUTE ( @Sql );
```

Comment: Did you try  `WHERE  [name] LIKE '%AccountsLive'` ?

Comment: no i didn't try it as i am an idiot!! thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put list of table names in a table variable and query them accordingly. I have also added schema as `dbo`, to make the name as three part name, assuming the table in the `dbo` schema.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(dbname sysname)

INSERT INTO @table(dbname)
SELECT NAME FROm sys.databases where name like '%AccountsLive'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(dbname) + '.dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS'
FROM    @table


EXEC( @Sql );
```

Comment: actually, i am getting an error on this one:

`Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator.`

any ideas?

Comment: @PeterK, can you please raise separate question. It seems some issue with different collation in different databases. Please put query and add separate question. It is different error.

Comment: ah sorry, thought it may be linked to this - will do!

Comment: @PeterK, no problem. sure.